Design a DFA that accepts even length binary strings that start with 0 and must not contain substring "001"
it will reject strings such as 001, 0001, 0010, 001001
Accepts = {00, 01, 0111, 0101, ..}

I built this one by mainly thinking about $2\times 3$ states (odd/even $\times$ counter for substring)
I think some states might be redundant here, will edit that in after figuring out if there are any.


Basically a base 3 counter with an extra state for the initial 0


I don't think this accounts for the even length constraint

The idea is to first draw a DFA that accepts all strings that have a substring $001$.

Now simply take its complement.

Now if you add the starts with zero $0$ condition, you end up the following DFA:

Now simply take the complement of this DFA.

Sorry, I missed the starts with $0$ part.

So what about the even length constraint?
